# Import XML into google document (not spreadsheet)

Tags: xml, macros, google-docs

I have an XML file. I would like to be able to pull into into a Google Document  (to eventually save as .doc). Is it possible to import an XML file into a Google Document?

Assuming I can pull it into google Doc, is there a way to create a Macro such that the parent nodes become Header1 and the children become bullets written in blue italics for example? i.e. I would like the macro to be able to render the XML file into a nice document looking format

I have looked around and I only seem to be able to find reference for XML imports into a google spreadsheet which is not what I am after here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but as of Office 2007 (I think), there are XML formats for Excel spreadsheets and Word documents (and, I think, all the Office family documents).

Some info about this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

I came across it myself when wanting to generate Excel sheets from XML; my method was to save a document that looked like what I wanted my output to be in Excel using the XML format, then open the XML in an XML Editor.

Once you know what your new XML needs to look like; you can write a general XSLT (depending on how complex your XML documents and your template are) to convert into Office format.

So, given your problem, I'd convert to Word format, and import that into Google Docs.